# Dependent variable "controlled" by a binary variable?

Tags: dependent-variable, controlling-for-a-variable

in my research the DV should be measured by means of an intent scale (Individual Entrepreneurial Intent Scale). For "controlling" if the answer in DV is correct, I want to include a binary Yes/No question asking if the user is really interested in becoming an entrepreneur.
So, does this approach makes sense?
If yes:

1. what kind of variable is this one (I don't think it is "control variable" and neither "marker variable"
2. how could I further analyze these two variables?
   Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The binary yes/no variable is a control variable if it's used to control for interest in becoming an entrepreneur.  It can be called a covariate, if interest in becoming an entrepreneur is not the primary research question, and rather there are other predictors that are of greater interest.  You could also call it a nuisance factor, the same way the age vs. blood pressure relationship can be controlled for by adding a gender (0,1) and/or a family history (0,1) variable - that is, you're interested in how age predicts blood pressure (DV) controlling for the nuisance factors gender and family history (which are not variables you are interested in, i.e. nuisance or confounder variables). Regarding terminology, you don't even need to mention the DV, but rather say "I want my regression model to also control for interest in becoming an entrepreneur via use of a binary yes/no question."